How can I manage the auto incrementation of an identifier in Zerolog and Lumberjack?
I use Zerolog and Lumberjack to create logs. Each log entry must have a unique identifier which must be incremented by 1 each time.
This is how I do it :
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "sync"

    "github.com/rs/zerolog"
    "gopkg.in/natefinch/lumberjack.v2"
)

type LogEntry struct {
    Level   string `json:"level"`
    ID      int    `json:"id"`
    Time    string `json:"time"`
    Message string `json:"message"`
}

func main() {
    mutexLog := sync.Mutex{}

    //fmt.Println("Start...")

    logFileName1 := "test.log"
    logFileName2 := "test.txt"

    // Open current directory
    currentDir, _ := os.Getwd()
    dir, _ := os.Open(currentDir)

    // Parse ".log" files
    notFirstEntry := false
    fileId := uint32(0)
    curId := uint32(0)
    files, _ := dir.ReadDir(0)
    for _, file := range files {
        if !file.IsDir() && filepath.Ext(file.Name()) == ".log" {
            logFile, _ := os.Open(filepath.Join(currentDir, file.Name()))
            line := 0
            scanner := bufio.NewScanner(logFile)
            for scanner.Scan() {
                line++

                var logEntry LogEntry
                if err := json.Unmarshal(scanner.Bytes(), &logEntry); err != nil {
                    fmt.Println("[ERR] json.Unmarshal:", err)
                    //continue

                    logFile.Close()
                    dir.Close()
                    return
                }

                curId = uint32(logEntry.ID)
                if notFirstEntry {
                    if curId != (fileId + 1) {
                        fmt.Println("[ERR]", file.Name(), ", line", line, ", Id:", curId, "=>", fileId)
                        return
                    }
                } else {
                    notFirstEntry = true
                }
                fileId = curId

                //fmt.Println("Level:", logEntry.Level, ", Id:", logEntry.ID, ", Time:", logEntry.Time, ", Message:", logEntry.Message)
            }
            logFile.Close()
        }
    }
    dir.Close()

    fmt.Println("Read file(s) [OK]")

    id := NewIdManager(fileId)

    logger1 := &lumberjack.Logger{
        Filename:   logFileName1,
        MaxSize:    1,
        MaxBackups: 1,
        LocalTime:  true,
        Compress:   false,
    }
    logger2 := &lumberjack.Logger{
        Filename:   logFileName2,
        MaxSize:    1,
        MaxBackups: 1,
        LocalTime:  true,
        Compress:   false,
    }

    mw := zerolog.MultiLevelWriter(logger1, logger2)
    writer := zerolog.New(mw).With().Timestamp().Logger()

    go func() {
        for {
            mutexLog.Lock()
            writer.Error().Uint("id", uint(id.GetId())).Msg("Test message")
            mutexLog.Unlock()
        }
    }()
    go func() {
        for {
            mutexLog.Lock()
            writer.Info().Uint("id", uint(id.GetId())).Msg("Test message")
            mutexLog.Unlock()
        }
    }()

    //time.Sleep(time.Second)
    select {}

}

// *********************************
type IdManager struct {
    id    uint32
}

func NewIdManager(initId uint32) *IdManager {
    obj := IdManager{id: initId}
    return &obj
}

func (obj *IdManager) GetId() uint32 {
    obj.id += 1
    return obj.id
}

https://go.dev/play/p/tBO8kCYozmS
I don't like this method: is it possible to integrate mutexLog and IdManager in writer object?
In my application code, I would like to replace this:
mutexLog.Lock()
writer.Info().Uint("id", uint(id.GetId())).Msg("Test message")
mutexLog.Unlock()

By:
writer.Info().Msg("Test message")

And I would like the locked state of the go-routines to be as short as possible
Note: time value of entry "id+1" must not be before the entry "id".

«is it possible to integrate mutexLog and IdManager in writer object?»–no. But its' possible to wrap this object with an object of your custom type which provides the required behavior (API) and eventually calls out to the object it wraps.

Here is a back-of-the-envelope sketch. (I have no prior experience with zerolog, so caveat emptor.)
